# Is a circle in the xy plane considered a graph?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

So I know a circle is not a function, but is it called a graph? Or can only functions have graphs?

Would the circle be better described as a level set of a multivariable function?

Comment: A graph is a collection of "paired objects", there are no restrictions like with a function. Viewed as a collection of ordered pairs, a circle is surely a graph.

Comment: Yes, it's the graph of an equation.

Comment: there are places where the term "graph" is reserved for those graphs which are attainable as the graphs of functions of a Cartesian variable. In such a context, a circle is not a "graph". Anyway, a circle is not a function period. Just like a line is not a function. The graph of a function $f(x)=mx+b$ is a line.

Answer (score 2):

A circle, i.e, an equation of the form $(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2=r^2$ is a *relation* on $\Bbb R$, that is, a subset of $\Bbb R^2$, which relates an element x with an element y, with some criteria, in this case, the circle equation.

To write it explicitly, the relation would be $C=\left\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2: (x-a)^2+(y-b)^2=r^2\right\}$.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to view a circle is as the image of the function

$f:[0,1)\to \mathbb R^2, \quad t\mapsto (a+r\cos 2\pi t,b+r\sin 2\pi t)$.

This approach has the advantage that it extends the idea to curves in $\mathbb R^n$.